# No overload for method 'btnLoginTest_Click' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have

```
<input type="button" id="btnLoginButton" runat="server" onserverclick="btnLoginTest_Click()" style="position: absolute;
                top: -1000; display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px" />
```

& my code behind has

```
protected void btnLoginTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Could someone please guide me as to what's happening & how to fix this? I need a postback to happen for the login controls. . Thanks in advance

Comment: change the `onserverclick="btnLoginTest_Click()"` to `onserverclick="btnLoginTest_Click"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try to remove "()" so your code should appear like

   onserverclick="btnLoginTest_Click"
2. If this don't work change method modifier to public.

Comment: & @ Aristos : Thank you both, that fixed the problem. But, now I want the Login controls to be posted back after the user has filled in them .. I have included the controls within an Update panel ..  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplLogin" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTestApplicationLoginAction" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLoginButton" EventName="ServerClick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Please explain better your problem

Comment: I have a Login control, in which an user can enter the name & password. after the user fills the login page & hits the button, the page has to get posted back. . . I have used an Update panel to the postback. But, it still does not work . Any suggestions?